# Node: get value of MAX(number) query

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

seems to be simple, but I'm struggling:

```
con.query("SELECT MAX(number) FROM cars;", function (err, result) {        
   // result: [{'MAX(number)' : 8}]
   let maxNumberAsInteger = ???
})
```

Thx!

Comment: Perhaps `let maxNumberAsInteger = result` ?

Comment: `result[0][Object.keys(result[0])[0]]` ? Messy but you get the idea

Comment: hey, that's working. thx